# MySql crazy join thorugh a grouping table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database structure with the following setup:

```
po: id, stockNumber, factoryId, other columns
order: id, stockNumber, factoryId, other columns
stock_number: id, stockNumber, groupId
factory: id, name, groupId
```

The important part here is the stock_number/factory tables. The groupId column is just an integer and if two or more rows in the table have the same value then their stock numbers/factory are considered the same. Typically this is used for different sizes of the same product.

What I'd like to do is write a query that will join "order" to "po" through the group of stock_number and factory so I can find orders with no matching po. Also the factory has to match the same way.

I have this query if I have a specific stock number/factory in mind but I'd like to update it to query the whole orders table for me:

```
SELECT id
FROM order
WHERE
  styleNumber IN (SELECT a.stockNumber FROM stock_number a INNER JOIN stock_number b ON a.groupId = b.groupId or a.id = b.id WHERE b.stockNumber = '123')
  AND factoryId IN (SELECT a.submitter_id FROM submitter a INNER JOIN submitter b ON a.groupId = b.groupId OR a.submitter_id = b.submitter_id WHERE b.SUBMITTER_ID = 'alpha');
```

EDIT: I came up with this query which I think might be on the right track. It only joins in the stock number so it doesn't do factory yet. Can anyone confirm if I'm going in the correct direction:

```
SELECT *
FROM order o
LEFT JOIN stock_number s_o ON o.stockNumber = s_o.stockNumber
LEFT JOIN stock_number s_p ON s_o.groupId = s_p.groupId
LEFT JOIN po p ON s_p.stockNumber = p.stockNumber
WHERE p.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how would you know which POs match to which orders for orders that *do* have a PO? Typically, you would have a field like `po_id` or something in your orders table, but I don't see that. Without knowing how you match orders that *do* have a PO, it's hard to know how to find orders without a PO.

Comment: An ORDER matches a PO if the stock number on the ORDER is in the same group as the stock number on the PO ~AND~ the factory on the ORDER is in the same group as the factory on the PO. In the program logic only one ORDER gets created per stock/factory group. So if there is a PO for factory A stock X and a second PO for factory A stock Y only one ORDER would get created assuming X and Y are grouped.

Comment: `styleNumber` should be `stockNumber`?

Comment: Sorry yeah. Unfortunately the database has styleNumber in some places and stockNumber in others. It's pretty fantastic :/

Answer (score 0):

Just join all the tables.

```
select o.id
FROM order AS o
JOIN stock_number AS sn ON sn.stockNumber = o.stockNumber
JOIN submitter AS su ON ON o.factoryId = su.submitter_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anti-join pattern.  In this example, it looks complicated because of the two relationship tables. But a query something like this:

```
SELECT o.id
     , o.stockNumber
     , o.factoryId
  FROM `order` o
  LEFT
  JOIN `stock_number` s
    ON s.stockNumber = o.stockNumber
  LEFT
  JOIN `factory` f
    ON f.id      = o.factoryId
   AND f.groupId = s.groupId
  LEFT
  JOIN `po` p
    ON p.stockNumber = s.stockNumber
   AND p.factoryId   = f.id
 WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

The anti-join pattern is easier to visualize with a simpler example. Say you had the `order` table (as in your example), and an `order_line` table, with rows related to the `order` table by the `order_id` column.

order_line:  id, order_id, othercolumns

To get `order` along with matching `order_line` rows:

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id
     , l.id AS line_id
  FROM `order` o
  JOIN `order_line` l
    ON l.order_id = o.id
```

To include rows from `order` that don't have any matching rows in `order_line`, we can use an outer join. We add the `LEFT` keyword:

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id
     , l.id AS line_id
  FROM `order` o
  LEFT
  JOIN `order_line` l
    ON l.order_id = o.id
```

That gets all rows from `order`, including rows that don't have a matching row in `order_line`.  The trick now is to exclude all the rows that have a matching row. For any rows that didn't have a match, the columns from `order_line` will be NULL. So we can add a test in the `WHERE` clause, to exclude rows that had a match.

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id
     , l.id AS line_id
  FROM `order` o
  LEFT
  JOIN `order_line` l
    ON l.order_id = o.id
 WHERE l.order_id IS NULL
```

That gets us rows from `order` that don't have a matching row in `order_line`.

We can use this same pattern in a more complicated query. We use *outer join* operations, and rows from `order` that don't have a matching row in `po` will have NULL values for the columns from `po`.